# Spark Physical Plan & Logical Plan

Tags: apache-spark

I have two questions:

1. With out adding any extra code to print logical and physical plan for the submitted spark job, Is there a way to see the physical and logical plan of the spark job running on the cluster.
2. Is there way to modify the execution plan dyanamicaly for the running spark job on the cluster for the better performance.

Please share your thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Both physical

   ```
   val df: DataFrame  = ???

   df.queryExecution.executedPlan
   ```

   and logical plan can accessed using `queryExecution` properties.

   ```
   df.queryExecution.logical
   ```
2. Yes, you can implement your own optimizer rules. This functionality in general not officially documented, but there are some external resources available:

   - [Learn the extension points in Apache Spark and extend the Spark Catalyst Optimizer](https://developer.ibm.com/code/2017/11/30/learn-extension-points-apache-spark-extend-spark-catalyst-optimizer/)

Comment: Fine, I would like to know how we can see the complete logical or physical plan when the job is running on the cluster.

Comment: I guess this post might help https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-optimized-logical-plan-in-spark